# CSS uglify — Grunt task

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, bem, uglifycss

I wonder are there any Grunt tasks which uglify CSS? Like in GMail code — all class names are random 2-3 letters.

I'm using AngularJS and grunt-angular-templates Grunt task to concatenate all templates in views/ folder to a single *templates.js* $templateCache file and I want to make this file as small as possible.

I have *index.html*, *main.css* and *views/* folder with bunch of HTML files — I want to uglify all CSS class names in all these files, 'cos I'm using BEM class name notation, so my CSS class names are rather long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the only reason to uglify is the length of classnames — just don't. gzip (use [zopfli](https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/) for the best result) makes all that long BEMish classes just same 2-3 letters long but on server level.

Comment: So, why did Google uglify all CSS classes everywhere in their services? Or may be it is only in Gmail, but anyway…

Comment: @artuska, The CSS is generated by GWT, not hand written.

Comment: what's the point of uglifying JS if it isn't to make long names shorter so you feed less into GZip?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a library to uglify css. If you want to use it in grunt then wrap it in a custom grunt task.

https://github.com/fmarcia/UglifyCSS

Comment: Well, this library does not uglify CSS.